# Trouble with ACTION_UP

Tags: android, events, touch, action, release

In my Fragment class, I inflate my fragment with an XML Layout. The Layout is a simple LinearLayout with an ImageView (of a wheel) in it. I want to do get the touch events that happend on my ImageView, here is the code :

```
 public class WheelFragment extends Fragment {


   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         // Inflate the layout for this fragment (Get the view from XML)
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wheel_layout, container, false);

        // Get the imageview of the wheel inside the view 
        ImageView wheelView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.wheel);


        // Set onTouchListener
        wheelView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Log.d("down", "ACTION_DOWN");
                }

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        Log.d("up", "ACTION_UP");
                }    
            }

            return true;      
        }
        });



        // Return the view
        return view;
    }   
}
```

I have no problem getting the ACTION_DOWN event but I can't get the ACTION_UP event.

I've tried to add a ACTION_CANCEL event which doesn't help (I saw on the forums that it might solve the problem).

I've also tried both value true/false for return.

Is there any simple way to get the ACTION_UP event working ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I eventually found my solution.

First my code was really messy because I had my OnTouch inside OnCreateView, then I needed to add "impements OnTouchListener" to my class.

Here is the code which works :

```
    public class WheelFragment extends Fragment implements OnTouchListener {


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

             // Inflate the layout for this fragment (Get the view from XML)
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wheel_layout, container, false);

            // Get the imageview of the wheel inside the view 
            ImageView wheelView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.wheel);


            // Set onTouchListener
            wheelView.setOnTouchListener(this);
            return view;
        }



    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            Log.d("down", "ACTION_DOWN");
        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            Log.d("up", "ACTION_UP");
        }
        return true;
    }



}
```

(Indeed if we return false in OnTouch it doesn't work, but I don't need any ACTION_CANCEL in order to  make it work)